# Android; Get text out of dynamic textfield adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have a dynamic adapter that fills up a listview with textviews with values read from a JSON file, here is an example ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LXCg.jpg ). Now I need to gather the user input from those fields and use it in a later part of my application, but my question is. when i generate textviews like that they all have the same ID right? so how can i specificly gather the user input of lets say the 2nd textview?

**Adapter**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_question_textfield, null, true);
--->        holder.editText = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt);
--->        holder.editTitel = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {...}

        holder.editText.setHint(HintArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID is an attribute of a view that scope of this attribute is limited by the inflated view group that includes this view.

for example if we have this xml file (item_view.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
      ...>
      <TextView
          ...
          android:id="@+id/textView_itemVew"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then we inflate this file several times (maybe in an adapter class) as below:

```
View item1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null,true);
View item2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null,true);
View item3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null,true);
```

now we can access the TextView view by it's ID but we should use the view group of this TextView to find it.

```
//Id's are the same but view groups no!
TextView editText_of_item1 = item1.findViewById(R.id.editText_itemVew);.
TextView editText_of_item2 = item2.findViewById(R.id.editText_itemVew);
TextView editText_of_item3 = item3.findViewById(R.id.editText_itemVew);
```

.

.

.

in your case you can add each EditText to a list to access it after whole list inflated ... like this:

```
List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<>();

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {  
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();  
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null,true);  

    EditText itemEditText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    editTextList.add(itemEditText);

    return itemView;  
};
```

there is useful example in [javaTpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-listview) website for you.

Comment: thanks alot for the explaination mohammad, spot on.